# What is the smallest element $a$ in $\mathbb{Z}/36\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\langle21\rangle=\langle a\rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

What is the smallest element $a\in\mathbb{Z}/36\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\langle21\rangle=\langle a\rangle$? So I know that $\langle21\rangle$ has order 12 in $(\mathbb{Z}/36\mathbb{Z})$. Does it have anything to do with finding the smallest element $a$? I mean, is the order relevant here?

Comment: If you know that the order of $21$ is $12$, then $\langle 21\rangle=\langle 3\rangle$, because for each divisor $d$ of $n$ there is a unique cyclic subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ of order $d$; clearly $3$ has order $12$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For every element $a\in\mathbb{Z_n}$ we have $\langle a\rangle=\langle \gcd(a,n)\rangle$. I'll give a short proof. Let $d=\gcd(a,n)$. $d|a$ so $a\in\langle d\rangle$ and that implies $\langle a\rangle\leq \langle d\rangle$. As for the other direction note that there are integers $k,l\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $d=ka+ln$. If we write this equation in $\mathbb{Z_n}$ then we get $d=ka$. Hence $d\in\langle a\rangle$ and that implies $\langle d\rangle\leq \langle a\rangle$. So $\langle d\rangle=\langle a\rangle$.

Now, in your specific example $\gcd(21,36)=3$ so $\langle 21\rangle=\langle 3\rangle$. So the $a$ you need to find is at most $3$. Easy to check that smaller elements of $\mathbb{Z_{36}}$ generate different subgroups. (look at their orders)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\,\,\left<21\right>\! = \left<a\right>\ {\rm in}\ \Bbb Z_{\large 36}\Rightarrow \overbrace{21\mid a\pmod{\!36}}^{\large 21\ {\rm divides}\ a\ {\rm  in}\ \Bbb Z_{\Large 36}}\! \iff 21j+36k = a\iff 3\!=\!(21,36)\mid a$

Comment: You mean $21\equiv a\pmod{36}$ ?

Comment: @Unk No, $\,a\mid b\,$ in a commutative ring $R$ means $a$ divides $b$ in $R,\,$ i.e. there exists $\,r\in R\,$ such that $\,ar = b.\,$  Hence $\, 21\mid a\, $ in $\,R =\Bbb Z_{36}\,$  means $\,21j = a,\,$ for some $\,j\in R.\,$ Said equivalently $\bmod 36\!:\ 21j \equiv a\,$ for $\,j\in \Bbb Z,\ $ i.e.  $\ 36k+21j = a\,$ for some $\,j,k\in \Bbb Z\ \ $